# How can I compare integers in python the same way CompareTo() in C# does?

Tags: python, c#, compare, compareto

As far as I know, in .NET Framework there is a method Int32.CompareTo(), which returns 0 if the numbers are equal, -1 if the number in the parenthesis is higher, otherwise 1. Is there an existing method for this, in python with the same return values, or do I have to write one myself?

Comment: Actually [`Int32.CompareTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.compareto?view=net-5.0#System_Int32_CompareTo_System_Int32_) is not guaranteed to return a value which is exactly equals to `-1` or `1` in corresponding cases, only the fact that it is more or lees than zero is guaranteed.

Comment: [`NumPy.sign()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) can be used: `numpy.sign(v1 - v2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe in some third-party library, but no, in "vanilla" Python 3.x there is no method to do that, though code to achieve something similar should be as simple as this:

```py
def compare_to(val1: int, val2: int) -> int:
    if val1 > val2:
        return 1
    elif val1 < val2:
        return -1
    elif val1 == val2:
        return 0
```

Or, for something closer to what you described using a custom subclass of `int`:

```py
class Int32(int):
    def compare_to(self, value: int):
        if self > value:
            return 1
        elif self < value:
            return -1
        elif self == value:
            return 0
```

Comment: I ended up suing something like the first snippet, thank you for the help.